# This issue occurred during build of the setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, setup-project

This issue occurred during build of the setup project.
why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That dialog behind the message box is a Windows Installer repair dialog. There is apparently a conflict between your install of SQL Server and Visual Studio. This typically means missing files or registry entries that result in the SQL install trying to repair itself. The event log should have MsiInstaller entries that say something about the problem. The message box is strange, but it might be indicating that it needs access to that MSI file in order to install a .cpp file.